# Add new user error in magento 1.5.0.1 

Tags: php, magento

Hi Guys I am getting a blank page and also redirect to assigned role page  after clicking Add New User --> System --> Permissions --> User --> Add New User.I checked log, report,exception error file, didn't find any error even it enabled. I cannot add new user.Can someone please point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has been fixed by changing content of core function getRowUrl in app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php

The core function :

```
public function getRowUrl($item)
    {
        $res = parent::getRowUrl($item);
        return ($res ? $res : '#');
    }

Replaced with:
public function getRowUrl($item)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $item->getId()));
    }
```

It worked great.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of question I have asked before and it was shut down for being to vague.

I know how frustrated you feel since it is impossible to find a solution on the net.

My experience has since taught me that if I get a blank page, it probably means my working environment, webserver,  IDE etc has just got too heavy.

My advice:

1. Restart your apache server
2. check Firefox is not eating too much memory in the Task Manager
3. Likewise with your IDE.
4. Also watch out for the resources being used by the JAVA JAR used by your IDE
5. Turn off XDebug since it has memory leaks.
6. Setup a cron to restart apache every hour.

Dont forget to clear the cache too!