# Magento : Admin Category form is not displaying

Tags: php, magento

I am working on magento project and has some issue with it, I have searched a lot over the net but didn't found anything related with this.
1) under admin > catalog > manage categories category form is not displaying, it display for a second and then disappears when loaded completely. 
2) I have used firebug to see if there is any data under the html but it removes after loading.
3) The ajax is not coming in admin firebug console.
4) I have got the ajax post url from firebug **NET** tab and opened it another tab and found response there.
5)  upon clicking on the left bar parent categories plus sign child are also not loading 
6) Any category is not loading...

Please help if any one has some previous experience or any guess what is going on.[image]

Updated error screen for chrome
[image]

Comment: Any error in error log?

Comment: the first step you can do now is to Re-index all the indexes.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will 100% resolve the issue, but pls try the solution given here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308916/add-new-user-error-in-magento-1-5-0-1 ..

Comment: @KalpeshMehta i tried reindex all the index by selecting all but its giving error and saying "Please select Indexes"

Comment: you may set display_errors to ON and see the error.

Comment: @chapagain yes i have checked with error but there is no error.. also I have got the ajax post url from firebug NET tab and opened it another tab and found response there.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta i have tried Sanjeev Kumar Jha solution but this didn't worked...

Comment: This ajax url status is coming as cancel in chrome console http://trendsetter.com.au/index.php/admin/catalog_category/categoriesJson/

Comment: Added a error console screen from chrome console the red ajax request are status cancelled...

Comment: This is happening to me, exactly the same issue, I see the categories for a second and then a "please wait" and then just blank. I'm starting a bounty!

Comment: I don't think anyone will give you exact answer till you share demo login to check the error exactly. could you do this ?

Comment: Do you guys have any custom extensions installed?

Comment: in that link you posted i can the see the categories working fine ? how can i repopulate the issue ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the client needed it fixed and we did a reinstall of everything and the issue never happened again :( But I wish there was a reason for this happening since it was obviously something that didn't only happen to me. I removed the login link for security.

Answer (score 0):

Given that both screen grabs indicate that one or more indexes are stale.  Start with those.

Next delete these folders, `/var/cache`  `/var/session`  `/var/full_page_cache` (under the Magento root)
You will need to login deleting `/var/session`

Disable any recently installed extensions or modifications.

Comment: Nah, that wasn't my case, Indexes were fine and everything else you said I already did. None worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some basic debugging to answer this question. Enable the error log and check it for errors on the page, this will hopefully give you an error message if you don't have one already.Check system log

If you have any new modules, remove them temporarily.Try reverting to an older version of the code that works, and then see what changed between the two versions.

Try to increase PHP memory_limit and check once.