# magento categories form in admin - not displaying

Tags: magento

My 'Manage Categories' page isn't displaying any category details.

The page seems to part load and then goes blank. Please see image.

I have no idea why this has happened, but I am concerned as I need to do quite a bit of work in the categories.[screenshot of categories in admim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyqAU.jpg)

I have seen this link but there was no conclusion to the problem.
[similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908506/magento-admin-category-form-is-not-displaying)

I can add code from the 'exception.log' and 'system.log' if needed.
Recently, a development company installed an 'order editor' module and some custom code, but they say that this had no impact on the problem I'm experiencing.

Hope someone can help
Thank you
Andy

//////////////////////////

Disabling the css 'display:none;' in 'Inspect Element', in the browser,  allows me to see the tab content, but this hardly helps the problem.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/028pM.jpg)

Comment: Do any of the tabs works? Log data will help.

Comment: Hi thebluefox - thank you for replying. None of the Tabs are working. Nothing happens when i click them. which log data would help? The exception.log or the system.log. They're both very long. The previous day from each? Thank you

Comment: Exception log, The best idea is to load the page you're having a problem with, then look at the last few errors in the file and you should see one that relates to this issue.

Comment: Hi thebluefox - I've just tried to view the categories in Admin and then checked the Exeption.log but the last entry was 11:59am today. The last entry in the system.log was 14:00pm today. So it looks like nothing is being reported for this problem. Driving me mad. Thank you

Comment: What about the js errors, is there any script error in the console ?

Comment: Viewing the page loading in firefox web console, i see this: unreachable code after return statement
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
ReferenceError: $j is not defined
The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.

Comment: Hi Sunil thank you for replying: yes there script errors:
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
ReferenceError: $j is not defined
The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it

Comment: This is the full js error split up:
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined[Learn More]  jquery-ui.js:11:3
 <anonymous> https://www.websitename.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/js/jquery-ui.js:11:3
 <anonymous> https://www.websitename.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/js/jquery-ui.js:3:2
ReferenceError: $j is not defined[Learn More]  0e98528d941692ff599bd7c453c9c6b1:2295:3

Comment: <anonymous> https://www.websitename.com/index.php/admin_securepath/catalog_category/index/key/0e98528d941692ff599bd7c453c9c6b1/:2295:3
The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.  blank.html

Comment: ReferenceError: $j is not defined[Learn More]  prototype.js%20line%20612%20%3E%20eval:2:3
 <anonymous> https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js%20line%20612%20%3E%20eval:2:3
 evalScripts/< https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:64
 collect/< https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:865:20
 each/< https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:825:9
 forEach self-hosted
 each https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:824:7

Comment: collect https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:864:5
 evalScripts https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:12
 bind/< https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:391:14
 delay/< https://www.websitename.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:416:14
The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.  blank.html

Comment: UPDATE: I found the problem!
It was indeed, a third party module. I have no idea why it suddenly started to conflict, but turning it off solved the problem. I will be looking into why.
Thank you all.
Andy